# Why and how: Missing symlink for python3?

Tags: python, macos

I am on macOS 10.15.7.

I need both `python2` and `python3`.
I am a beginner which is why I often struggle to understand many terms. A fellow student told me that the `->` are symlinks.

When running `me$ which python3` I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
```

But when checking `ll /usr/bin/python*`

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    75B Oct  9  2019 /usr/bin/python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    82B Oct  9  2019 /usr/bin/python-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    75B Oct  9  2019 /usr/bin/python2 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    75B Oct  9  2019 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    82B Oct  9  2019 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    31K Oct 30  2020 /usr/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    76B Oct  9  2019 /usr/bin/pythonw -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    76B Oct  9  2019 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

Everything looks the same except for the line concerning python3.

1. Why does `which python3` return a different path than the one I see when `ll`ing `/usr/bin/python*`. I mean both exist...
   So, why is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3` preferred?
2. Why is there no symlink for python3? What went wrong during the installation?
3. Is it "safe" to just `manually` generate a symlink between the `/usr/bin/python3` and the `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3` as shown [here](https://osxdaily.com/2015/08/06/make-symbolic-links-command-line-mac-os-x/). `ln -s /path/to/original/ /path/to/link` Being a beginner I'd rather ask the internet first ;)

I'm happy to edit my question following your suggestions as I'm here to learn - and hopefully soon also to help.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share how you installed python3? The python present in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/` are the system python executable that macOS uses. They get symlinked into /usr/bin/ to make them available to the user but it is normal (and ok) to overwrite those symlinks with user installed executables.

Comment: @MatteoZanoni honestly I don't remember how I installed, I'm sorry its a few months back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `which` man page

> which returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be
> executed in the current environment, had its arguments been given as  commands  in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell

and in the options list

> ```
>    -a     print all matching pathnames of each argument
> ```

So, without the `-a`, `which` simply prints the first 'hit' on your `PATH`. So for example, if `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`, `which python3` will return only one.

I would be willing to bet that your running `which -a python3` will return:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin
/usr/bin/python3
```

Your install went fine, you just have more than one `python3` executable installed. There is also no need to do any extra symlinking.

Comment: Thanks, if there is no extra symlinking needed - why is python2.7 symlinked then?

Comment: could be lots of reasons, different install processes might or might not use symlinks. But really, as long as the actual executable is on your PATH they are superfluous. Sometimes you might want symlinks for hygeine reasons, or because you want aliases for certain commands, e.g. your `python2` and `python2.7` are aliases

Comment: But is it bad that I have 2 different paths for python3? Do you think I should change the question to "Why do I have 2 different paths for python3?"

Comment: Not really. You don't really have '2 different paths for python3'. You have 2 python3 executables, both are on your PATH. Perhaps they are even 2 different versions of Python3. Compare the output of `python3 --version` with `/usr/bin/python3 --version`

Comment: Indeed: 
```
me$python3 --version
Python 3.9.1
```
```
/usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```
In that case, should I remove one of them, as this redundancy is not necessary? I don't need a specific python3 for any programs I use.

Comment: 'I don't need a specific python3 for any programs I use' - that you are aware of... some important system thingy might need a specific version or expect to find `/usr/bin/python3`. If it isn't broken, then don't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a fair bit of research here.

The 2.7 Python is the Apple-used Python, best leave it alone. I would also leave the existing /usr/bin/python3 alone dont replace it with a symlink. As to results of which, they depend on the contents of the PATH variable. wherever something is first found is where it is gotten from. `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/` must precede `/usr/bin` in PATH and they both have a `python3` entry.

The easiest way to have a stable Python to work with (and no, I don't recommend Python 2.7 as part of that) is to use [macport](https://www.macports.org/) or [brew](https://brew.sh/) to install Python, which install Python symlinks in a given directory, **separate from system directories like `/usr/bin`**.

(but do note chepner's comment about brew, he looks to be on to something and he's probably forgotten more about Python than I ever knew)

Then use [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) or an equivalent to pick the correct Python to use for a given project.

I would keep as a general policy leaving the contents of `/usr/bin` alone, unless you have some really good reason.

This is a [primer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119265) on the macos directory structure, with emphasis on PATH.

I you want to see what's in your PATH, you can `echo $PATH` or do the following:

create file `myshellutils.sh`:

paste in the following:

```
showpath ()
{
    IFS=':' read -a array <<< "$PATH";
    for index in "${!array[@]}";
    do
        echo "$index ${array[index]}";
    done
}
```

save it, then type `source myshellutils.sh`.  That creates a new shell function, `showpath`.

which you can use as follows (some stuff edited out).

```
(venv38) me@bin$ showpath
0 /Users/me/.cargo/bin
1 /Users/me/venv38/bin    this is where the VirtualEnv-activated version of Python lives
3 /opt/local/bin  where macports puts things 
4 /usr/local/bin  where brew puts things.  Yes, I had to use both.
5 /usr/bin  Apple stuff, leave alone.
6 /bin
7 /usr/sbin
8 /sbin
10 /opt/local/sbin
12 /Users/me/bin
```

Last, but not least... a symlink?  Whuzzat?  A pretty clever idea actually, it's basically a pointer, or a marker if you wish, to another file somewhere else with a potentially different name.

so, say your programs point to which Python to run

**foo.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("hello")
```

so, first let's `which -a python` (nice call on -a, L.Grozinger )

which gets

```
/Users/me/venv38/bin/python
```

let's cd there, then `ls -l python*` with a cut to get rid of all the user and size stuff.

```
$ls -l  python* | cut -c 46-

python -> python3.8   1️⃣ your entry point for where foo.py looks for "python".  now look for "python3.8"
python3 -> python3.8
 2️⃣ which resolves to where macport installs 
python3.8 -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8  binaries.
```

The clever thing?  As you install Python 3.9, it will be linked to by `python -> python3.9` and `foo.py` will never care.

Comment: Its weird that the first 2 sentences are there

Comment: Well, the OP thought it necessary to complain about upvotes on old stuff and also didn't tell us they were on a Mac.  Yes, it can be frustrating to see a 26K rep user whose main contribution 16 years ago was a "how do I do use `git commit`" but that's life.

Comment: There's an argument to be made that [one shouldn't use `brew`'s Python](https://justinmayer.com/posts/homebrew-python-is-not-for-you/), either. Personally, I use `nix` to provide a specific version of Python for development.

Comment: @chepner interesting.  My Python is from macports, brew is very secondary, I only use it because some packages, like a MS-supplied MSSQL driver, IIRC, were only on brew.  Nothing against brew, personally, just started out on macport.  However, a relative newcomer to Python/macos might be best served by a package manager.

Comment: The OP wrote the last lines to **decrease the likelihood** of the question being closed immediately, by drawing attention to the fact that the OP is a beginner and might ask "stupid-beginners-questions" but still does as best as can. 

The OP is not frustrated by other ppl getting 26K rep for asking how to `git commit`. The OP gets frustrated when no one helps, but quickly closes questions instead. This is because the OP feels that this is a place where people like learning and helping  but some times it doesn't seem so ;) (I also assume I should delete this comment soon as it is off topic)

Comment: I suspect a similar argument would apply to MacPorts. `nix` is nice because package dependencies are all pinned transitively, so if you want packages that use 6 different versions of Python, you just have 6 different versions of Python installed, and each package is linked to the correct one.

Comment: @chepner according to your link that's a recent-ish change.  unless macports followed suit, and my last `port selfupdate` is shamefully out of date, it's probably ok.

Comment: Ah, right, I misremembered exactly what the issue with brew was. (I clearly did not reread the page before linking to it here.)

Comment: @JLPeyret now that I read brew... I've used that probably to install one of the 2 python3 I got. Why do you suggest that "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 **must** precede /usr/bin in PATH"
? Because it's 3.9 and more up to date than the other one?

Comment: Nope, because the PATH is fairly stable but binaries or more likely symlinks get deposited at different points in it.  To take my own PATH, if I symlinked `python` in `/Users/me/.cargo/bin` (Rust's entry), then `which python` would end showing that, because it found `python` in the first directory it looked at.

Comment: @ilamengl  no worries.  my comment was a bit snarky.  and the Python comunity generally prides itself on being newbie-friendly. but yes, there are a lot of people who really really have strong feelings about what SO should be like and should not be like.  they will be merciless because you did not realize your question was asked 7.9 years ago, using a different title, and close it as a duplicate.  still, a big part of asking system or multi-component questions (webserver + database server issues for example) is to specify your system, your webserver, your rdbms and potentially the versions.